# Nullable Reference Type allowing null with AllowNullAttribute

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

```
public class Child : Parent
{
    [Parameter("Name", DefaultValue = "John")]
    public override string Name { get; set; }

    // More than 5 similar properties and methods ...
}
```

Consider the class above in C# 8 with Nullable Reference Type enabled. The `Child` class is in a plugin which is supposed to be implemented by 3rd party developers, where the developer will inherit `Parent` (which is part of a framework) and might add some specific implementation.

The `Name` property will be populated on construction of the class that is done via Activation.

Currently I am getting *a non-nullable property is uninitialized* warning, when I decorate name with `[AllowNull]` the warning disappears, as expected.

However, the attribute `[Parameter]` implementation, which is part of the framework, guarantees that this property will be initialized.
I tried in `ParameterAttribute` to inherit `AllowNullAttribute` but `AllowNullAttribute` is sealed (I am not even sure if I am successfully able to inherit `AllowNullAttribute`, that the warning would go away).

It is ridiculous to ask the implementer of the class to decorate every property with `AllowNull` in addition to `Parameter`. Also, asking them to disable this warning on the class level will interfere with with their internal implementation.

Any suggestion on hiding this warning if a property is decorated with `[Parameter]`?

Comment: What is the `ParameterAttribute` here?

Comment: "the attribute [Parameter] implementation guarantees that this property will be initialized." If that attribute is not a part of the .Net framework, I don't think the compiler will care much about it's implementation.

Comment: The whole point is that it's a **warning**, not an error. Since you know the warning is incorrect in this case, just ignore or supress it. Applying `AllowNullAttribute` here would in fact be the wrong thing to do, since your `ParameterAttribute` guarantees the opposite!

Comment: Maybe try the preprocessor directive `#nullable`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I updated my question, it is part of the framework.

Comment: @ZoharPeled this is why I wanted Paramter to inherit AllowNull, to associate it to the framework

Comment: @IanKemp you are right, I might have asked the wrong question. I want to remove any null warning as it won't be null after construction.

Comment: @404 It is a flawed framework architecture, in my opinion, to ask the implementers to do that, given that the implementers are 3rd party.

Comment: Having to add `= null!` (or in this case perhaps `= default!`) does not seem particularly onerous. AFAIK there is no way to bestow on arbitrary attributes the same magic as the built-in attributes; that would require a brand new mechanism in the compiler.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: I don't know that it's particularly _onerous_, per se, but I can certainly understand why it would be _desirable_ for a framework to account for this in order to make plugins as simple and fool-proof as possible, while simultaneously communicating expectations to both code analysis and the compiler.